# Python multiprocessing process skipped for loop element inconsistently

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, for-loop, multiprocessing

I have some python code that utilize multiprocessing.Process to terminate a function if the function's execution time exceeds certain threshold. I am using a for loop to pass the parameter of the function into multiprocessing.Process, and I collect the output of the function after the execution. Specifically, the simplified version is as follow.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def foo(arg, return_dict):
    """
    The function does something and modify return_dict.
    It does not return anything. 
    """
    print("The input arg is: " + arg)
    
    # Do Something that maybe time consuming
    
    return_dict['a'] = # Some value
    return_dict['b'] = # Some other value

def process(arg):
    """
    The function passes parameter to multiprocessing.Process.
    The execution will stop if exceeds 10 seconds. 
    """
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(arg, return_dict))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    
    return return_dict.values()

def main(parameter_list):
    """
    This is the main function. It uses a for loop to pass parameter 
    to process(), which execute foo with the parameter within the time
    limit. 
    """
    for arg in parameter_list:
        _ = process(arg)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parameter_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    main(parameter_list)
```

But what happened is the expected stdout should be as follow,

```
The input arg is: A
The input arg is: B
The input arg is: C
```

**Sometimes I got only two of them**, not three. For example,

```
The input arg is: B
The input arg is: C
```

What's even weird is that while keeping the code unchanged, **sometimes I got all three of them**. This output inconsistency is really confusing and I am not able to reproduce the exact same output every time, which makes the debugging process difficult. I would very much appreciate any insights and suggestions!

Reference:

- Using multiprocessing.Process to terminate function after some time (I know another approach is to use **signal**. But I am on Windows unfortunately.)- [Kill function after a given amount of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915527/kill-function-after-a-given-amount-of-time)
- Maybe a similar issue - [Multiprocessing/for loop is skipping elements randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267693/multiprocessing-for-loop-is-skipping-elements-randomly)

Comment: Are you getting the same results if you increase the sleep time to, say, 60s? The process might be terminating before it starts

Comment: After I correct your code so that it can run (there is no variable `parameter_lsit` and you need to assign actual values to the dictionary in function `foo`), I cannot duplicate your error on Windows or Linux.  In function `process` try using a context manager: `with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:` so that the manager process terminates on return. However, for efficiency sake, it's better to just create the `manager` in function `main` *once* and pass it as an argument to `process`. Tag your question with the platform, e.g. *linux* or *windows*. **And post your *actual* code.**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your error is not reproducible. Also, you clearly did not post your actual code since the code you did post could not possibly execute. Was there something in your actual code that could be causing the problem? Who can tell until we see it?

Comment: @Booboo Thanks a lot for your comments! Exactly, my biggest roadblocks here is that I am not able to reproduce it with the same code. Regarding the actual code, I am only omitting some code in the `foo` since it's complicated. But no matter what the actual code is, foo should be executed three times and print out the argument when executed. But in fact, this is inconsistent. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nothing in addition to what I have already said -- but try either of my two suggestions regarding creation/termination of the `Manager` instance. Perhaps having multiple instances running is somehow causing the problem (???).